# JSON Parsing Android Java

Tags: java, android, json

i would like to parse this json but im not able to do it. Heres the Json Structure:

[image]

For example: I would like to get String product type => Car

this Code doesnt work:

```
JSONObject mainData = response.getJSONObject("decode");
String productType = mainData.getString("Product Type");
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decode` is an array not an object so it should be

```
JSONArray mainData = response.getJSONArray("decode");
```

And then you can get inside objects using the index.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = mainData.getJSONObject(0);
String answer = jsonObj.getString("label"); //Make
```

Comment: i dont know why but when i try to parse it, my string is empty...                    
       JSONArray mainData = response.getJSONArray("decode");
         ProductType = mainData.getJSONObject(3).getString("value"); //Product type

Comment: oh sorry, I messed up a little bit. Edited now, it's working fine, I tested it.

Comment: Glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Gson

Define your class with something like that

```
public class YourClass implements Parcelable {

    private int price;

    @SerializedName("price_currency")
    private String priceCurrency;

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getPriceCurrency() {
        return priceCurrency;
    }

    public void setPriceCurrency(String priceCurrency) {
        this.priceCurrency = priceCurrency;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
        dest.writeInt(this.price);
        dest.writeString(this.priceCurrency);
    }

    public YourClass() {
    }

    protected YourClass(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        this.price = in.readInt();
        this.priceCurrency = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<YourClass> CREATOR = new Creator<YourClass>() {
        @Override
        public Pessoa createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new YourClass(source);
        }

        @Override
        public YourClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new YourClass[size];
        }
    };
}
```

and try to convert your json with something like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

YourClass yourClass = gson.fromJson(yourJson, YourClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this correctly, you'll need a custom `JsonDeserializer`. Like this:

```
public class CarDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Car> {
    @Override
    public Car deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        Car car = new Gson().fromJson(json.toString(), Car.class);

        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json.toString());

            car.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(object.getString("price_currency")));
            car.setBalance(object.getJSONObject("balance").getInt("API Decode"));

            JSONArray decodeArray = object.getJSONArray("decode");

            for (int i = 0; i < decodeArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject decodeObject = (JSONObject) decodeArray.get(i);

                if (decodeObject.get("label").equals("Make")){
                    car.setMake(decodeObject.getString("value"));
                } else if (decodeObject.get("label").equals("Manufacturer")){
                    car.setManufacturer(decodeObject.getString("value"));
                } else if (decodeObject.get("label").equals("Plant Country")){
                    car.setPlantCountry(decodeObject.getString("value"));
                } else if (decodeObject.get("label").equals("Product Type")){
                    car.setProductType(decodeObject.getString("value"));
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("CarDeserializer", e.toString(), e);
        }

        return car;
    }
}
```

The `Car` object looks like this:

```
public class Car {
    private int price;

    private transient Currency currency;
    private transient int balance;

    private transient String make;
    private transient String manufacturer;
    private transient String plantCountry;
    private transient String productType;

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Currency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(Currency currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getPlantCountry() {
        return plantCountry;
    }

    public void setPlantCountry(String plantCountry) {
        this.plantCountry = plantCountry;
    }

    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(String productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }
}
```

If `Currency` doesn't work for you, you can change that one to a `String` type like this:

```
@SerializedName("price_currency") private String currency;
```

And change the `getter` and `setter` accordingly.

If you have more objects in the `decode` array. You can add them as more branches in the deserializer.

This is used like this:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Car.class, new CarDeserializer());

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

gson.fromJson(myJsonString, Car.class);
```

Note: The `transient` keyword in the `Car` class indicates to `Gson` that it shouldn't attempt to automatically parse the json for those fields.

Note 2: You'll need to include Gson in your project if you haven't already added it.

Comment: Why do you think `org.json` is not sufficient?

Comment: @AshvinSharma I just find `Gson` to be much better for automatic Json parsing. With `org.json`, you have to do the parsing manually. In the majority of cases, I can simple feed a String and a class into `Gson` and it handles it. It's also very useful in cases where I want to output an object to the log. If all you want to do is pick a single data point out of the Json, `Gson` would be overkill, but if you want to parse a json string into a class, Gson is killer.