# Parsing JSON response?

Tags: java, json, translators

I'm having trouble parsing the JSON response for the http post request. What is the issue regarding Json parsing here?

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("url");

    post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    textConv text = gson.fromJson(reader.toString(), textConv.class);
    System.out.println(text.text);
```

OUTPUT

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
    at gsonTest.main(gsonTest.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: can you print "content" as well? looks like you have [ ] array returned and not a json object

Comment: And where is raw response?

Comment: Above link is the post request. You can see that it returns a json response

Comment: [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802588/5675692) to similar problem might help

Comment: @AshvinSharma Yes it does look similar. Just learned that I have to arrange the class to be able to handle the parsed object. Which I clearly haven't. Will try that way and update.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your 'text' field in the object array of strings:

```
String[] text
```

Your response has array, and you try to parse it into String object:

```
{"code": 200, "lang": "en-ru", "text": ["жизнь"]}
```

Look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057695/parsing-json-array-using-gson) for example of parsing arrays.

Comment: Yes. the error is gone. But the parsing hasn't happened

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[Ljava.lang.String;@3b0fe47a

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been stuck here for hours.. :)

Comment: All good. It's working now. :) This helped [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181072/how-to-access-jsonarray-in-a-jsonobject-using-java) Thanks so muck for help :)